# He goes to school by foot

Tags: single-word-requests

Can you please correct this sentence. I am bit confused about this sentence. I think its not a correct sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

'by foot' is a perfectly acceptable prepositional phrase to denote walking as the method of transportation (EDIT: though '*on* foot' is supposedly more common). I hope that helps.